# Stationary charge in varying magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

Usually this issue is examined in loops, coil etc with currents. I am referring to a realistic situation that can be easily tested in places like LHC.

Suppose there is a charge moving at near (.999999991) c approaching and overtaking a stationary charge A (minimum distance = 1 cm): the magnitude of the electric/magnetic field will increase until A is overtaken, an then it rapidly decreases.

Do you know if A will oscillate or move at all because of the magnetic force? If it does, by what law and formula , and, in what direction?

Edit:

I am asking about the effects of a varying magnetic field, if the example above can cause misunderstandings, please substitute the approaching charge with a magnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically a sitting charge q should feel the [Lorentz force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html) of the fields of the approaching  Q

[image: lorfor]

One would have to model the approaching and distancing  E and B  but I would just expect a scattering, no oscillations.

Comment: Since A has v=0, Lorenz force is zero. But when the charge is approacing its magnetic  field increases, so another law should be at play (Faraday/Lenz?) (besides the ordinary electrostatic attraction/repulsion). When the charge overtakes A and passes on, the magnetic field decreases and the effect (if any) would be rereversed, so, all in all, A should just bob, oscillate once, like a cork on water when a wave is passing.

Comment: That "$\times$" cross product symbol can be easily confused for $x$

Comment: @lambertwhite Its velocity is zero before the Q is close,at the approach the electric field of the Q will induce an attractive or repulsive motion to q by its electric field, which will give a v to q which will then interact with the B of the moving Q.  Lorenz force is enough, but complicated .

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis  the image is copied from the hyperphysics link.  A physicist should not be confused, between two vectors there is either a dot or a cross procuct.

Comment: Why are you excluding an effect of B on A when v=0? why does an increasing Bfield have an effect on the charges in a piece of metal? it is not due to Lorenz, is it? Electric force will make A move away from/toward Q in a parallel direction so Lorenz force will be zero

Comment: I am not excluding it once it starts having a velocity by being attracted or repulsed. The perpendicular angle in your problem will be only for a delta(t) or so.  Anyway all this is handwaving without a solution, if it can be done analytically.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic scattering between free charges due to electromagnetism was [first performed by Rutherford](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rutsca.html#c1).

In order to preserve total momentum, any momentum change $\Delta \vec p_c$ in the moving particle must be balanced by a change $\Delta \vec p_A = -\Delta \vec p_c$ in the momentum of the (initially) stationary particle.  However if the incident and target masses are dissimilar, the momenta may match without very much change in the velocity of the less-massive particle.

Comment: Are you hinting that there is a collision?

Comment: One usually discusses the "impact parameter"; the link is a good starting point.